# Combine Observables to run in parallel

Tags: android, optimization, rx-java, observable

How to combine both so they run in parallel or in serial?

```
Observable<Data>) dataRequestOne;
Observable<Data>) dataRequestTwo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Parallel:

```
Observable.merge(dataRequestOne, dataRequestTwo)
```

Serial:

```
Observable.concat(dataRequestOne, dataRequestTwo);
```

Comment: The `merge` only works in parallel if the observables are on separate threads.

Answer (score 0):

Try zip operator : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

```
Observable.zip(dataRequestOne, dataRequestTwo, new Func2<Data, Data, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call(Data o, Data o2) {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use serial response in onNext for each request than you need to use merge operator

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html

```
Observable.mergeDelayError(
                dataRequestOne.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()),
                dataRequestTwo.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this is you can do this:

```
Observable.just(dataRequestOne, dataRequestTwo).flatMap(new Func1<Data, Observable<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Data> call(Data data) {
            return Observable.just(data)
                             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io);
        }
    });
```

Now each request will be processed on a separate thread. FlatMap also has an optional maxConcurrent parameter so if you had more observables you could control the amount of threads that are processing the requests if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

An example to run 2 `observables` parallel in a time using `merge`

```
val parallelObservables = mutableListOf<Single<String>>()
val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)
val schedulers = Schedulers.from(executor)
for (i in 0..4) {
    val observable = Single.create<String> {
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        it.onSuccess("" + i + " " + Thread.currentThread().name)
    }.subscribeOn(schedulers) // need to subscribe here
    parallelObservables.add(observable)
}

Log.i("TAG", "start")
Single.merge(parallelObservables)
    .subscribe {
        Log.i("TAG", "complete $it")
    }
}
```

`Output`

```
2021-04-22 16:31:51.790 32016-32016/com.example.androidrxtest I/TAG: start
2021-04-22 16:31:53.891 32016-32055/com.example.androidrxtest I/TAG: complete 0 pool-1-thread-1
2021-04-22 16:31:53.894 32016-32056/com.example.androidrxtest I/TAG: complete 1 pool-1-thread-2
2021-04-22 16:31:55.894 32016-32055/com.example.androidrxtest I/TAG: complete 2 pool-1-thread-1
2021-04-22 16:31:55.897 32016-32056/com.example.androidrxtest I/TAG: complete 3 pool-1-thread-2
2021-04-22 16:31:57.896 32016-32055/com.example.androidrxtest I/TAG: complete 4 pool-1-thread-1
```